# Tell TypeScript that pragmatically created exports exists in module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

If one creates exports in a programmatic way:

Example:

```
const peeps = ['peep1', 'peep2', ...]
peeps.forEach(peep => exports[peep] = mainMethod.bind(null, peep))
```

what is the best way to tell TypeScript about these methods? At present they are not showing as an export when I attempt to import them as expected. How can I define them as exports that TypeScript understands?

I am trying to **avoid**:

```
export const peep1 = mainMethod.bind(null, 'peep1')
export const peep2 = mainMethod.bind(null, 'peep2')
```

**EDIT:**
I may need to make it clear. It it works fine, I do not have an issue with the export itself, I have an issue in that because they are pragmatically created that vscode is not aware they exists because said export is not in the file at design time. I am trying to get TypeScript to recognize said exports at design time.

Comment: What module system do you use ? Is that export the only export in your module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I guess I simply had to add:

```
declare export function peep1(age:number):any;
declare export function peep2(age:number):any;
```

Basically, I had to write a d.ts file for it because they are dynamically created exports.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the problem is constructing an object that has properties defined in a string array.

```
// The helper insures we get the type of peeps as ('peep1' | 'peep2')[] not string[]
const peeps = helper('peep1', 'peep2'); 
// Define a type that maps the constants to properties
let methods : {
    [P in typeof peeps[number]]: () => void
} = {} as any;
// Add the members to the object
peeps.forEach(peep => methods[peep] = mainMethod.bind(null, peep))

function helper<T extends string>(...array: T[]) : T[]{
    return  array;
}
```

Depending on your module system you can export the `methods` object in one of two ways.

If you use `amd`, `commonjs` or `umd` you can use export assignment:

```
// methods.ts
// code above 
export = methods;

//usage.ts
import * as m from './aaa'
m.peep1();
```

For other module system you can use default exports:

```
// methods.ts
// code above 
export default methods;

//usage.ts
import m from './aaa'
m.peep1();
```